# Combine static var with parent's

Tags: php, class, static, extend

This is what I'd like to be able to do:

```
class Test {
    public static $test = 'boo';
}

class Two extends Test {
    public static $test = parent::$test.'hoo';
}

// Two::$test == 'boohoo'
```

Well, specifically combining 2 arrays, but this illustrates it.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible because you can't evaluate anything when declaring a variable.

Something like:

```
class A {
    $seconds_in_a_day = 60*60*24; // invalid
    $seconds_in_a_day2 = 86400; // sour but valid
}
```

is invalid even.

You can move it to the constructor.

```
public function __construct() {
    self::$test = parent::$test.'hoo';
}
```

Aside from all that .. just don't do it. Save your future self a lot of work and find another more intuitive solution :P

Comment: Thanks, I was really hoping for some miraculous workaround :)
In my particular case this value gets called before construction, or I wouldn't be asking this question.

Comment: Well, the constructor is really just a glorified initializer, so write an initializer.